# Flex list switching itemRender of selected item

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

In Flex 4 (beta 2), I have a list control populated from an XMLListCollection.

What I would like to do is when an item is selected in the list, use a custom item renderer on the selected item as well as the item that appears just prior to the selected item in the list.

I am using a spark list control, but I am open to alternate components if the solution makes sense.

Here is the strucutre of the xml used to populate the XMLListCollection

```
<Images>
   <Image>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Url>http://www.mydomain.com/image1.png</Url>
   </Image>
   <Image>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Url>http://www.mydomain.com/image2.png</Url>
   </Image>
<Images>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For now it was decided that we didn't need to have the item to the left of the 'hovered' item change its state as well.  So, Christopher's solution is the best way to go.  Thanks again Christopher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use one itemRenderer which has a number of states which vary based on what the current `data` is?  That would accomplish your goal in a much faster, simpler, and maintainable fashion.

Comment: I currently have an itemRenderer that behaves differently for the list item currently being hovered over.  That works great.  

My remaining problem is how do I determine the item to the left of the item being hovered over and changes its itemRenderer state as well.